# Applying a function that may fail to all values in a list

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I want to apply a function `f` to a list of values, however function `f` might randomly fail (it is in effect making a call out to a service in the cloud).

I thought I'd want to use something like `map`, but I want to apply the function to all elements in the list and afterwards, I want to know which ones failed and which were successful.

Currently I am wrapping the response objects of the function `f` with an error pair which I could then effectively `unzip` afterwards

i.e. something like

`g :  (a->b) -> a -> [ b, errorBoolean]`

`f : a-> b`

and then to run the code ... `map g (xs)`

Is there a better way to do this? The other alternative approach was to iterate over the values in the array and then return a pair of arrays, one which listed the successful values and one which listed the failures. To me, this seems to be something that ought to be fairly common. Alternatively I could return some special value. What's the best practice in dealing with this??

Comment: FYI: A list in Haskell must be homogeneous (i.e. can only hold 1 type of thing). In your case you need to return a tuple `(b, Bool)`. Of course the proper way is to use Maybe or Either.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `f` is making a call out to the cloud, than `f` is undoubtedly using some monad, probably the `IO` monad or a monad derived from the `IO` monad.  There are monadic versions of `map`.  Here is what you would typically do, as a first attempt:

```
f :: A -> IO B -- defined elsewhere
g :: [A] -> IO [B]
g xs = mapM f xs
-- or, in points-free style:
g = mapM f
```

This has the (possibly) undesirable property that `g` will fail, returning no values, if any call to `f` fails.  We fix that by making it so `f` returns either an answer or an error message.

```
type Error = String
f :: A -> IO (Either Error B)
g :: [A] -> IO [Either Error B]
g = mapM f
```

If you want all of the errors to be returned together, and all of the successes clumped together, you can use the `lefts` and `rights` functions from `Data.Either`.

```
h :: [A] -> IO ([B], [Error])
h xs = do ys <- g xs
          return (rights ys, lefts ys)
```

If you don't need the error messages, just use `Maybe B` instead of `Either Error B`.

The `Either` data type is the most common way to represent a value which can either result in an error or a correct value.  Errors use the `Left` constructor, correct values use the `Right` constructor.  As a bonus, "right" also means "correct" in English, but the reason that the correct value uses the `Right` constructor is actually deeper (because this means we can create a functor out of the Either type which modifies correct results, which is not possible over the `Left` constructor).

Answer (score 2):

You could write your `g` to return a [Maybe monad](http://www.haskell.org/all_about_monads/html/maybemonad.html):

```
f: a -> b
g: (a -> b) -> a -> Maybe b
```

If `f` fails, `g` returns `Nothing`, otherwise it returns `Just (f x)`.